# Is "Stanford populi" bad Latin?

Tags: english, word-usage

In their ["Open Loop University" concept vision](http://www.stanford2025.com/open-loop-university/), Stanford introduces "populi" as the next conceptual step after "alumni". Examples of usage follow.

"...we now have a populi of 215,000 ongoing students..."

"Populi could earn C3 by teaching master classes..."

Is this bad Latin? "Populus" does not mean "person as a part of a population/nation", it refers to the population/nation itself, so populus-populi is not similar to alumnus-alumni. Am I missing something?

If so, what would be a better usage for the second example? Perhaps it would help to use a word whose singular actually means a person, e.g. socius, amicus, civis even?

Comment: _Alumni_ itself, as referred to former students, is corrupted Latin, IMHO: it is short for _antiqui alumni_, removing the adjective that gives sense to the concept

Answer (score 6):

You are right, this is terrible Latin. They could have said: "we now have a **populus** of 215,000 ongoing students". If it really has to be Latin, that is.

Comment: Cheers @fdb! Any thoughts on a better solution? I thought maybe "socius" conveyed what they were going for best.

Comment: Populus has the advantage of being a collective. Socii might refer to (research) "fellows" or "associates" and thus not include the student body.

Answer (score 2):

A traditional term for 'the [student] body' is actually *corpus [studiosorum]*, cf. French *corps*. English 'body' is no doubt simply a translation of the Latin. So I see no need for a new, synonymous term to describe "ongoing students" (itself hardly a felicitous term). Such a novelty *should* suggest ignorance to an academic.

Answer (score 1):

The citizens of a *populus* are indeed the *cives*, so yes, calling them *populi* is not correct. I don't quite get it though. They're just students again, *discipuli*. What makes them a *populus*?

> Open Loop pioneer Phil Pizzo once noted, “Where we once had an association of alumni looking fondly back at Stanford as just one time in their lives, we now have a populi of 215,000 ongoing students who know that Stanford is there—and theirs—throughout a lifetime.

Does this mean that 215,000 alumni have continued engagement with the university? It's unclear, but that's the sense I get.

In this case, what about a word for 'returners'? We could do the perfect participle of either of the two deponent verbs for 'return', which yields [*reversi*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Drevertor) or [*regressi*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dregredior). You even have Latin phrases like [*regressus domum*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=regressus+domum) or [*reversus domum*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=reversus+domum) meaning 'having returned home,' which I think Stanford is trying to get at.